# Android: Getting orientation (landscape/portrait) on Activity launch

Tags: android

My Activity needs to monitor the orientation of the device.  Now this works great with `onConfigurationChanged()`, but I also need to know orientation when my Activity starts.

So how do find out the current orientation of the device in my `onCreate()`, for instance?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm no expert but this works for me, in `onCreate()`:

```
int display_mode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (display_mode == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_land);
}
```

Comment: I was looking in `Activity` for that `getConfiguration()` method... Android why must you be so obtuse.  Thank you ShadowGod!

Comment: There is no reason for you to set your views this way. Android is build auto-magicly to use the right ones based on their folder locations. You can place your default layout /res/layout/ and the landscape one in /res/layout-land with the same name. During onCreate Android detects the layout and uses the correct resource. The same may be done with screen density and other things.

Comment: Ahhh thanks Chris as a beginner I didn't realize that thank you.

Comment: You can do this for a lot of things - docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources