# get screen mode of current activity/view

Tags: android, sdk

How to get the screen mode (portrait/landscape) from an application? 
I have find no method about this in class Activity/View.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589503/android-getting-orienation-landscape-portrait-on-activity-launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();

if(width>height)
{
//Landscape
}
else
{
//portrait
}
```

Comment: As per [hackbod's explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone/2795935#2795935) this answer is not correct. `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` is the only recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, which uses the new getRotation instead of the deprecated getOrientation(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
display.getRotation();
```

Comment: @Femi, the answer in that thread refers to a deprecated API method and is no longer the appropriate solution.